# gem found by ```gem info``` but not with ```bundle info```

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm new to ruby and rails, so I have a simple question. On my machine the gem "matrix" will be found by `gem info`:

```
root@tRdmInt-deb12:/usr/share/redmine# gem info matrix

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

matrix (0.4.2)
    Author: Marc-Andre Lafortune
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/matrix
    Licenses: Ruby, BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0

    An implementation of Matrix and Vector classes.
```

But `bundle info` says that the gem is unknown:

```
root@tRdmInt-deb12:/usr/share/redmine# bundle info matrix
Could not find gem 'matrix'.
```

Why can't bundle find the gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed the gem using `gem install matrix`. If you want the bundler to detect the gem, you need to add it to the /usr/share/redmine/Gemfile and do a `bundle install`